# Convert string array to strings with a whitespace separating them

Tags: java

I have a string array (not arraylist), what is the best way to print it into a new string with whitespace separating them, lets say

```
String array = {"a", "b", "c"};
```

I want to print it to "a b c", how can I do that?

Comment: Use for loop and do string concate operations on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to get String with whitespace.

```
String[] array = {"a", "b", "c"};
String output = "";
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    output += array[i] + " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Arrays.toString(String[]). It will return a String of the format:

```
[a, b, c]
```

Then you can simply replace "[", "]", "," with an empty string, and you'll be left with only the whitespaces:

```
String[] str = { "a", "b", "c" };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str).
              replace("[", "").replace("]","").replace(",", ""));
```

Output is: a b c

Of course this will only work if your strings doesn't contain one of those characters!

Comment: cool. I haven't think this way :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public String printOutput(String[] input){
     String output="";
      for(String text :  input){
      output+=" "+text;
      }
   return output;
}
```